# How can I pass arguments to a command that is run via psexec.exe?

Tags: autoit, psexec

I am running the following command format:

```
PsExec.exe -i -s \\\\ip -u username -p password "\\\\shared\driver\path\autoitscript.exe" "\\\\shared\driver\path\car.jpg"
```

The exe file takes in a file path and enters the path in a file upload window. The exe file is an AutoIt script (.au3 file converted). The script uses ControlSetText to enter the file path in the upload window. I can see the exe file being run on the remote machine, but for some reason the file path is not being entered. Is there something wrong in the way i execute the psexec command? Locally the script executes correctly.

Comment: #RequireAdmin for sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using ControlSetText to send the file path into the upload window. That did not work. Instead use ControlSend or Send.

Comment: You may want to flesh this answer out a little for extra context. I don't see ControlSetText or ControlSend anywhere in the question.